# Is moving Civi easier than the docs say?

Tags: documentation

I've moved Civi a few times in the past 2/3 years, following the docs esp. the PhpMyAdmin method.  Lately the restore using this method has failed even though I followed the docs - because of foreign key restraints (error 1215) - so I've emptied the target db and done a full backup & restore with no problem. The last move I just made a full backup & restore with no problems - this is at 5.7.3 level. So I guess that improvements have been made & for systems at 5.7 level moving Civi is more straightforward than the docs say.  This is good news of course!  Perhaps it's just the docs that need updating, but I wonder what other users have found?

Answer (score 1):

The triggers have a DEFINER that needs to exist and have the right permissions so if the db user is different you might run into some problems there. If by "full" you mean you are also restoring the system mysql.user table that might be ok but that might cause other problems with the hosting provider control panel depending how they are set up.